# ASP.NET MVVM Pattern

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns, mvvm

where do we fit MVVM pattern creational? structural? or behavioral?

Comment: MVVM is for WPF and Silverlight, not ASP.NET. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx You might be looking for MVC pattern for ASP.NET...  http://www.asp.net/mvc

Comment: There are at least a couple of frameworks for using MVVM or MVP esque patterns with ASP.NET Web Forms e.g. http://aspnetmvvm.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

MVVM used in Silverlight and WCF is a structural pattern.